# Accents generate errors with moderncv class

Tags: errors, unicode, moderncv, accents, input-encodings

When using accented characters (e.g. ë) I get the following error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ële not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

A minimal working example is given below.

To the best of my knowledge my .tex file is UTF-8 encoded (I'm using TextMate on OS X and the file command also says it's an UTF-8 file).

If I comment out the \moderncvstyle{casual} command, a PDF is generated without errors, but a blank space is printed instead of the ë character.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```
% minimal working example

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\name{Richard}{Kranendonk}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Somestreet 1}{1000 AA Somecity}
\phone[mobile]{01~234~567~89}                    
\email{myemail@isp.com}                                
\homepage{http://www.doesnotexist.com}                          
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{Pasfoto_160x213}
\quote{Januari 2014}

\begin{document}

\cventry{1999}{Presentatie vaardigheden, Commerciële vaardigheden, Onderhandelen, Conflicthantering}{Kenneth Smit Communicatie Trainingen}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no errors. Are you sure that your file is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: I get the error precisely if I encode the file in Latin-1. Save it as UTF-8, or use the `latin1` option for `inputenc`

Comment: Strange. Just to be sure I did a 'Save as..' with encoding set to UTF-8 in TextMate 2.0, still get the errors. I'll check if this is a known issue in TextMate.

Comment: Are you able to report any news?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. I found out I need different encoding for my iMac and MacBook to prevent the errors. Probably some different makeup of the environments.
I decided to be pragmatic and uncomment one of these LaTeX commands depending on the machine I'm working on:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}           % works on iMac
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % works on MacBook Air
```